# Manifest peer latest not found error during hyperledger installation.

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger

I have just started exploring the blockchain technology. I was working around the installation part by following [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html) tutorial.

I have created /mychain directory and docker-compose.yml. when i run the command `sudo docker-compose up` it starts pulling member services `hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc`. But after that it throws error

`Pulling vp0 (hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest not found`

Please someone guide me on this.

Comment: Change the tag from latest to `x86_64-1.0.2` in the compose file and see if it helps

Comment: can u please tell me where exactly i can find this?

Comment: Yes of course, https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags/

Comment: I have tried with `sudo docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.2` and then run `sudo docker-compose up`. But still its showing the same error.

Comment: You need to change the tag in the compose file

Comment: Thank you so much! it was so minor problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tag from `latest` to `x86_64-1.0.2` in the compose file. There is no `latest` tag for this image. You can get all available tags on below link

https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add any tags to `fabric-peer`, docker try to pull image with `latest` tag. And there is no `latest` tag for `fabric-peer`.

So you should use an available tag, see  available tags [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, the problem was fabric failed to download peer binary with tag '2.2.1' and 'latest' during 'curl' command execution  with following error.

Peer image getch failed:

====> hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.1
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.1
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.1

**Solution which worked for me:**

Have downloaded peer 2.2.1 manually using below command

```
docker pull "hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.1"
```

**NOTE:**

"network.sh up" also throws error as it is trying to use peer binary of latest tag which is not present in docker hub. Since 2.2.1 was the latest I have created tag manually using below command.

```
docker image tag hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.1 hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```

Then it worked. You can use your version accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For HyperLedger 2.3, I found that the 'network.sh' file needs to be edited.
This file can be found under 'fabric-samples/test-network' directory.
Find the constant 'IMAGETAG' and replace its value "latest" into "2.3" or whatever your peer version is.
This constant will be referenced in all the docker-compose files.